# Linear first order PDE method of characteristics line integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, line-integrals, characteristics

I am confused about the following.

Suppose we wanted to find a solution $u(\textbf{x}, t): \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to the PDE

$$ u_t + \textbf{b(x)}\cdot \nabla u = 0, $$
with some initial data function $g(\textbf{x})$ on $\mathbb{R^n} \times \{t=0\}$.

By the method of characteristics, we have the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} \textbf{x}(t) = \textbf{b}(\textbf{x}(t)); \ \textbf{x}(0) = \textbf{x}_0\\
\frac{d}{dt}z(t) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Since we don't know the form of $\textbf{b}(\textbf{x}(t))$, we can't write an explicit solution to this ODE. My notes say that one can write

$$  \textbf{x}(t) = \int_0^t \textbf{b}(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + \textbf{x}_0  $$
as an implicit form of the solution to the characteristic ODE, but I don't see where this is possible. I get as far as

$$ x_i(t) = \int_0^t b_i(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + x_i^0 $$

where $b_i$ is the $i$'th component function of $\textbf{b}$, and $x_i$ is the $i$'th component function of $\textbf{x}$.

I'm really not too sure about what the notes are saying, because what I have doesn't seem to lead to the same thing as what's in the notes, and furthermore, the result of integrating is a vector, not a scalar, which I find confusing. Also, I am not sure if I should really be writing
$$ x_i(t) = \int_0^t b_i(\textbf{x}(s)) \|\textbf{x}'(s)\| \ ds + x_i^0, $$
because after all aren't I integrating $b_i$ along a characteristic curve?
I'm pretty confused here, and I really need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: the meaning of $$\textbf{x}(t) = \int_0^t \textbf{b}(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + \textbf{x}_0$$ is precisely $$ x_i(t) = \int_0^t b_i(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + x_i^0, \quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$i.e. the integral is to be interpreted componentwise. Note that $ds$ is not arclength

Comment: I feel like the above probably doesn't completely solve your issues but I'm unsure what else to say, so comment and/or edit and I can say more

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't understand I guess how we can do an integration and have the result be a vector--i thought always the result had to be scalar.

Comment: And I am still not sure if the componentwise integral I wrote down is missing the "arc-length" infinitesimal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\textbf{x}(t) = \int_0^t \textbf{b}(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + \textbf{x}_0$$
is meant to be understood as $n$ different identities

$$x_i(t) = \int_0^t b_i(\textbf{x}(s)) \ ds + x_i^0, \quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$
i.e.
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}= \int_0^t\begin{bmatrix}b_1(\mathbf x(s))\\ \vdots \\b_n(\mathbf x(s))\end{bmatrix}ds := \begin{bmatrix}\int_0^tb_1(\mathbf x(s))ds\\ \vdots \\\int_0^tb_n(\mathbf x(s))ds\end{bmatrix} $$
The integrals on the right are (assuming $\mathbf b$ is continuous, say) normal honest Riemann integrals; that is, one could say,
$$ \int_0^tb_i(\mathbf x(s))ds \overset{\text{def}}= \lim_{|\Delta P|\to 0} \sum_{s_k\in P} b_i(\mathbf x(s_k)) (s_{k+1} - s_k)$$ where $P$ denotes some partition $s_0,\dots,s_n$ of $[0,T]$ and the limit sends the partition mesh size $\Delta P := \sup_k |s_{k+1} - s_k|$ to 0. Note $ds$ in this case does **not** indicate a line integral using arc length parameterisation.

The integral identity/identities came about by using the 1-D Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $n$ times: if $f'=g$ (and $f,g$ are nice), then $f(t) = \int_0^t g(s)ds + f(0)$. You just need to apply this with $f=x_i, \ g=b_i\circ \mathbf x$. No mention of any geometry here, and no fussing with $\|x'(s)\|$ either.

You may actually check that the definition for a Riemann integral makes 100% perfect sense when the output is a vector, so long as you check all convergence results in the correct (i.e. vector) norm; so the above line (with the obvious modification of replacing $b_i$ with $\mathbf b$) is a perfectly good definition of $\int_0^t \mathbf b(\mathbf{x}(s)) \ ds$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, but I think I'm still confused--because If I were asked to integrate a scalar function $b_i(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a curve $\textbf{x}(s)$, parametrized by $s$, I would need $||\textbf{x}'(s)||$, no?

Comment: @P.Gillich yes, the situation there is very different. You are here given a function $b_i(x(\cdot)) : [0,t] \to \mathbb R^1$. So you use your 1D tools. But, if you were asked to compute a line integral (and I would strictly require you to say $\huge line$ integral), then you use the definition of a line integral.

Comment: so if it were a line integral (sorry), I would have attempted to integrate $$\int_cf(\textbf{x})d \textbf{x},$$ and then put in the parametrization for $\textbf{x}$--but in this case, I was never integrating with respect to the line $\textbf{x}$ to begin with?

Comment: @P.Gillich yes, though I was taught to only integrate vector valued functions with $d\mathbf x$ ie $\int_C \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf x = \int_0^1\mathbf F(\mathbf x)\cdot \mathbf x’ ds$, not bolding  the x with a more suggestive letter is for the scalar one $\int_C f d\ell = \int_0^1 f(\mathbf x) |\mathbf x’| ds$

Comment: I'm all over the place--sorry about that. I really appreciate your help!